# Angular2.1.2 can not get header in response headers

Tags: angular

I have one issue with Angular2.1.2. I can not get header in http response.

I have response headers in browser:

[image]

But I can't get header in http response:

```
this.http.post(url, body)
            .map(res => res)
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                   //do something
                }, (err) => {
                    let authenticateErr = err.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate");
                    
                    //authenticateErr is null
                });
```

This is headers I see in http response

[image]

It worked in Angular beta6, and when I upgraded to Angular2.1.2 it don't work. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey @Sophia did u find the solution for this ?

Comment: @girl_who_codes, I can't resolve it, so I have changed to another solution.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if you passing the response header to your err when you are throwing it. Try this

**Service**

```
public extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || { };
}
public handleError (error: any | Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
}

public postData(): Observable<User[]>{
        return this.http.post(url, body)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

**Component**

```
this.yourService.postData(url, body)
   .subscribe(
   (res) => {
   //do something
  }, (err) => {
   let authenticateErr = err.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate");
 //you should have header here
});
```

Comment: I tried It and It didn't work `.map(...).catch is not a function`.

Comment: You need to import those. You can also import rxjs and it has the all operators.